# node.js serialport from working Python Script

Tags: python, node.js, serial-port

I'm trying to get data from a serial port. I've got a working python script, but I need the code in node.js.

Here ist the python script:

```
import serial
import time
import io

ser = serial.Serial('COM3')

ser.timeout=1

while(True):

try:
    ser.write(b'M00');
    ser.write(b'p');
    s0 = ser.read(26)

    print(s0)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    ser.close()
    break

except:
    pass
```

Now I tried to rewrite this code in javascript and came up with this code:

```
const SerialPort = require('serialport');

SerialPort.list((err, ports) => {
  console.log(ports)                
})

var myPort = new SerialPort('COM3', {
   baudRate:9600
})

myPort.on('open', onOpen);
myPort.on('data', onData);
myPort.write('M01');

function onOpen(){
  console.log("Open connection");
}

function onData(data){
  console.log("on Data " + data);
}

while(true){
  console.log(myPort.read())
}
```

Unfortunatley I can't get it to work. My guess is, that maybe I have to pass binary code to my port. Do you know a sollution? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found my mistake. Just forgot to also write the "p" to my port.